# Ssh permission denied for authorized keys - openssh version - OpenSSH_7.6p1,?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, openssh

I have my ssh keys stored in /etc/ssh/www-user.authorized_keys.
In my /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I have a line saying

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/%u.authorized_keys
```

My /etc/ssh has the permission, 700

```
drwx------    2 root     www-user       936 Apr 28 06:28 ssh
```

The authorized file has the permission, 600.

```
-rw-------    1 root     www-user       451 Apr 28 06:28 /etc/ssh/www-user.authorized_keys
```

When I do an ssh using user-id www-user, I get the following error saying -

```
debug1: trying public key file /etc/ssh/www-user.authorized_keys
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/etc/ssh/www-user.authorized_keys': Permission denied
```

What should be the permission of /etc/ssh/www-user.authorized_keys?
What am I missing here? How to know what permission it is required?
Is there any man page or documentation on it? Or how do I check this in the openssh source code?

[openssh source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/tree/V_7_6)

Answer (score 0):

Only root has permission to access files.

You should change back folder permission to 755 and folder's group owner permission to root (this is the default configuration) and change file owner to www-user:

```bsh
chmod 755 /etc/ssh
chown root:root /etc/ssh
chown www-user:www-user /etc/ssh/www-user.authorized_keys
```

I'd store another location these authorized_keys files.